# Answer Sorting different Behavior

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, sorting

Recently I have seen the popular answer of Jon Skeet on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result), I found out that Jon Skeet answer it in just 16 minutes so, to look whether someone replied earlier than Jon Skeet I sorted by **Oldest** and found out that Skeet answer is still at top but the fact was that Jacob answered earlier than Skeet, He replied just in 5 minutes. On finding I found out that it was by design that **Accepted Answer** is always remains at top.

But in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33969/best-way-to-implement-request-throttling-in-asp-net-mvc?answertab=oldest#tab-top) on sorting it behaves different and it moves the correct answer to bottom by sorting answer time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That accepted answer was posted by the user that asked the question. Self accepted answers [don't float to the top](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/):

> **No change in sort order.** Normally, accepted answers are “docked” under the question. This is not true for owner accepted answers; they stay in standard sort order like any other answer.